# c# json Newtonsoft Не удается найти метод из документации (.Net4.7.2)

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.5

Использую следующую библиотеку и документацию

https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp#jsonserializer

Мне требуется изменить сериализацию System.Text.Json на Newtonsoft.Json из-за того что в System.Text.Json отсутствует параметр ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore.

Но при попытке использовать:

```
var jsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
jsonSerializer.OptionsProvider = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
};
client.JsonSerializer = jsonSerializer;
```

Компилятор не распознаёт объект **NewtonsoftJsonSerializer()** он изменился или что с ним стало?

как быть?

единственное что он предлагает это установить google.apis.core но это явно не то...

Comment: [Кхм...](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Почти в самом начале 
Игнорировать циклические ссылки
System.Text.Json в .NET 5 и более ранних версий поддержка не поддерживается

Comment: А вы где ищите NewtonsoftJsonSerializer? Вообще, это вроде как кастомный сериализатор от разработчиков той либы, на которую ссылайтесь. И там нужно установить их либу SocketIOClient.Newtonsoft.Json, чтобы воспользоваться этим сериализатором.

Comment: Простите, а вы пробовали вообще это все проделать? Или слепо верите тому, что написано? Ок, [проверю за вас](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhy0C.png). Как видите, 4.7.2, простой консольный проект, в NuGet только `System.Text.Json` (со всеми его зависимостями), в правом окне можете видеть код, который я взял по ссылке выше, там можете заметить `ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles`, ну а снизу, результат, который также, соответствует тому, что показано в документации. Ну а вот вам результат [без опции](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDyN4.png), как видите, ошиька. Так может всеж поддержка есть?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ И правда работает... спасибо за проделанную работу! А можно еще вам задать вопросик?) я создаю проект "Библиотека классов (.net Framework 4.7.2)" а манифест у меня заблокирован "Внедрить манифест с настройками по умолчанию", почему так?(

Comment: я его в ручную написала, до при компиляции он не вкладывается в проект, пока добавляю ручками)

Comment: Хм, а смысл в манифесте у библиотеки? Не, не спорю, в некоторых случаях это может и нужно, но... это единичны случае, вы уверены, что у вас такой? Ну а так, манифест вам мешает добавить IDE, попробуйте сами, руками прописать в .csproj его, ну или вот один из вариантов [добавления](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899535).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Как раз этот случай, библиотке будет для большой программый и там он необходим. Нашла параметр в IDE "Копировать в выходной каталог" - помогло, Спасибо вам не первый раз выручаете=)